# How to display comment's meta fields value in admin comment section?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have added an extra field in wordpress comment form for user age. 
I have added the field like this way :

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','add_comment_fields');
function add_comment_fields($fields) {
    $fields['location'] = '<p class="comment-form-location"><label for="location">' . __( Location ) . '</label>' .
        '<input id="location" name="location" type="text" size="30" /></p>';

    return $fields;

}
```

And also I have saved the meta value in comment meta table by using 'comment_post' action.
Now I have to display this comment meta value in admin comment section. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try bellow code, hope you will able to see your extra field in admin section(Here i use age as meta key).

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_comment', 'comment_add_meta_box' );
function comment_add_meta_box()
{
 add_meta_box( 'my-comment-title', __( 'Your field title' ), 'comment_meta_box_age',     'comment', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function comment_meta_box_age( $comment )
{
    $title = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'age', true );

   ?>
 <p>
     <label for="age"><?php _e( 'Your label Name' ); ?></label>;
     <input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>"  class="widefat" />
 </p>
 <?php
}
add_action( 'edit_comment', 'comment_edit_function' );
function comment_edit_function( $comment_id )
{
    if( isset( $_POST['age'] ) )
      update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'age', esc_attr( $_POST['age'] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be these links will be helpful

(1) http://blog.ideashower.com/post/15147134893/wordpress-plugin-extra-comment-fields

(2) http://make.wordpress.org/docs/plugin-developer-handbook/10-plugin-components/custom-list-table-columns/

Answer (score 0):

If you successfully saved the meta value you can use the `get_comment_meta` function to retrieve the value.

pattern:

```
<?php $meta_values = get_comment_meta( $comment_id, $key, $single ); ?>
```

in your case this might work:

```
<?php $meta_values = get_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'location', true ); ?>
```

see the full documentation for more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_meta